# Problem with the auto-suggestor for OpenID / Flickr

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, openid

The OpenID login-widget-thingy has a bug. When selecting Flickr as the OpenID provider, it asks for my Flickr username (to login to http://flickr.com/). However, the flickr OpenID url is http://flickr.com, regardless of my username.

Selecting Flickr as provider: [Selecting Flickr http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/1514/loginorregisterstackove.png](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/1514/loginorregisterstackove.png) (kaboingsingen beeing the username)
Result: [Response http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/1514/loginorregisterstackove.png](http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/1514/loginorregisterstackove.png)

Comment: Don't get it. Can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: It works for me with Firefox 3.0. What browser are you using?

Comment: Added some screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

removed flickr from the sub-list, since flickr no longer requires a username -- and basically has merged with Yahoo.

So, short answer, use the Yahoo button now!

Comment: Yep, works for me.